# Knockout can't get transitions to work

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I've been working with Knockout for a few days now. Things have been going relatively smoothly but I've run into an issue. I cannot seem to get an animation transition running here. Ideally I'd like to be able to fade out the singular element on the destroy event. I'd also like to be able to animate the whole table on a page transition. I cannot get any to work because the element is always 'undefined'.

This is my foreach bind:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: { data : $root.displayResults(startValue(), endValue()), beforeRemove: hideElement }'>
```

But when the function is called I get an undefinied jQuery error

```
self.hideElement = function(elem) {
    $(elem).hide(300)
}
```

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q6Ma/4/) and let me know what you guys think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that KO will call the `beforeRemove` callback multiple times based on your template: In your case it will be a text node, the tr, and another text node.

So you need to filter out the text nodes and only do the hide when the `elem.nodeType == 1` which means the node type is an element:

```
self.hideElement = function(elem) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 1) 
       $(elem).hide(300)
}
```

Here is a [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/7q6Ma/5/) with a working delete functionality I've also added some logging to see how many times the `beforeRemove` gets called.

So also the [Animated transitions example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)'s `hidePlanetElement` method.

Comment: Thanks Nem, I actually did figure this out last night and got the thing working. I'm liking knockout but there's definitely a lot going on behind the scenes that you've got to work out when you first pick it up.